# What does it mean that a function continuous in an environment $M_0(x_0,y_0)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I saw this term in a theorem, and I don't know what it means.

Saw this originally here:

> If function $z = f(x,y)$ definied around $M_0(x_0, y_0)$ and have partial derivatives $f'_x(x, y), f'_y(x, y)$ around this point $\implies$ $f(x,y)$ differentiable in $M_0$.

## My question:

what does it mean **around $M_0$**? What does it mean **in the environment of $M_o(x_0, y_0)$**?

What does the word ***`around \ environment`*** means? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not say in the *environment* of $M_0$, but in a *neighborhood* of $M_0$.

A neighborhood of $M_0$ is an open set $N$ containing $M_0$ (that means there exists a small enough ball $B(M_0,r)$ such that $B(M_0,r) \subset N$).

Examples:

1) $[0,2]$ is not a neighborhood of $0$ because any open interval containing zero goes outside the set.

2) $[0,2]$ is a neighborhood of $1$ since $1 \in (1/2,3/2) \subset [0,2]$.

and so on..

Comment: What is a ball?

Comment: Come on... :) A ball of center $x_0$ and radius $r$ is the set of points $x$ which are at a distance smaller than $r$ from $x_0$. Just imagine a 3D ball.

Comment: Oh .. I'm having troubles to think in these terms at 3:24PM .. Sorry for that .. I'll read it again and If I'll understand I'll accept it..

Comment: You may find Google helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics) more details here.